# Как добавить перенос на другую строку (\n) после каждого 80 символа в php?

Tags: php, строки

Как добавить перенос на другую строку (\n) после каждого 80 символа в php?

поступает строка, но она очень длинная, и желательно принудительно добавлять \n после каждого 80 символа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей есть функция [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 80, "\n");

echo $newtext;
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!